# What does the forward slash mean in app.get('/',function(){...}); in express.js?

Tags: javascript, express, web

I just started learning express.js and in that, we do app.get('/'.function(){...});,
i want to know what does that / means.I tried to look into google but really couldn't get which will simply describe it without getting too technical.

Comment: `/` means root; root of the application.

Comment: so can you describe a bit what does app.get('/'.function(){...}); means in a whole.

Comment: It means when there's a GET request to the root of the application, execute the callback?

Comment: ok, thanks for your help.appreciated

Comment: Look at the [API documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.get.method)

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you're running your server on localhost port 8080. Then the **root** URL of your server is http://localhost:8080.

Thus when you write

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  console.log('hi');
})
```

You're saying

> When someone sends an HTTP GET to http://localhost:8080, I log "hi" into the console.

- `/` means just your root URL

  - `/example` in contrast would mean http://localhost:8080/example
- `function(){}` is what you want to do in response

Comment: Thanks, I got it completely now, appreciate your help.